# VTK: Subset of Points with same color

Tags: visualization

I have a set of points, among which a subset needs to have the same color in vtk file format. For ex.  all agents with table value

> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

will have same color. Here is my vtk

```
POINT_DATA 11
SCALARS Gid FLOAT
LOOKUP_TABLE table
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
LOOKUP_TABLE table 11
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0  1.0 1.0
```

Could anyone tell me how to do the same in paraview, I mean the associated parameters that need to be changed in Paraview, or is it that the vtk itself does not do as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I can give you is in the development version of ParaView and won't be available until ParaView 4.1 comes out in a couple of months. It uses the idea of categories. What I did was create a Wavelet source, contour that with isosurface values of 100, 200, 220, and 240, then use the Clip filter to look at the "insides". After that is done, go to the View menu and select check Color Map Editor. In the color map editor check the Interpret Values As Categories. The click on the button with the 3 overlapping squares (red, yellow and blue). This will bring up the discrete values of your variable. In the first column you can click inside to choose an annotation color (I did green for the first 3 colors and red for the last). I also specified annotations for them: a, b, c and d. I attached an image to show you what it looks like.[image: color categories]

If this doesn't work for you maybe you can try playing around a bit with the color map editor to get it to work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution but here is what I did, I just used the *Default Lookup table*

```
POINT_DATA 11
SCALARS Gid FLOAT
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0
0
2
2
4
5
5
7
10
10
10
```

Here *points with the same* **default LOOK_UP** *Values* will have the same color in any color scale chosen in your visualizer.